# Do HTML entities not work in innerHTML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fun()
  {
    var str = document.getElementById("h").value;
    document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = str;
  }
</script>
<?php
 $str = "<html>some other text";
 echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.htmlspecialchars($str).'" id="h"/>';
 echo '<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click"/>';
 echo '<span id="s">change here</span>';
?>
```

In the above example, some html entities (obtained from PHP's htmlspecialchars() function) along with some plain text is stored in a hidden field. I want to display this content in the span element when user clicks the button. But my observation is that only the plain text is shown in the span ignoring the html entity part which should be like <html>. But it is displayed as desired if I use alert(str) in the javascript. I want to know why this happens.Do HTML entities not really work with innerHTML in the context of the above code?

Comment: HTML entities work just fine with `innerHTML`: http://jsfiddle.net/3dgm5xhx/ Perhaps (since PHP has nothing to do with this) you could add a Stack Snippet (the `<>` button) to your answer demonstrating the problem you're having, as currently it's not clear.

Comment: Show the example `$str`.

Comment: I just want to know why document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = str; results in "some other text" in the span leaving html tag as shown in the code

Comment: Be clear about a) what values you have, b) what you expect to happen and c) what actually happens. "Not working" is unanswerable. It works as it's supposed to, likely your expectation is simply wrong, but we cannot deduce that because we don't know how you *expect* it to "work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've figured out the question. Taking the PHP out, your HTML might look like this if `$str` contains `<strong>boo</strong>` and so `htmlspecialchars` outputs `&lt;strong&gt;boo&lt;/strong&gt;`:

```
some other text
<input type="hidden" value="&lt;strong&gt;boo&lt;/strong&gt;" id="h" />
<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click" />
<span id="s">change here</span>
```

Later, what gets assigned to the span's `innerHTML` is `<strong>boo</strong>` (without entities). And you see `boo` in boldface, like this:

```js
function fun() {
  var str = document.getElementById("h").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(str);
  document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
some other text
<input type="hidden" value="&lt;strong&gt;boo&lt;/strong&gt;" id="h" />
<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click" />
<span id="s">change here</span>
```

That's happening because the text in attributes **is HTML**, which is something people tend to forget. So the `value` of your input is `<strong>boo</strong>` (without entities), as the entities have *already* been interpreted (when the HTML was parsed).

When you assign that to your span's `innerHTML`, you're asking that string to be interpreted as HTML a *second time*, and it ends up creating a `strong` element with `boo` in it.

If you want to add that text to the span *without* re-interpreting it, use a text node:

```
  var t = document.createTextNode(str);
  var span = document.getElementById("s");
  span.innerHTML = ""; // Clear old content
  span.appendChild(t); // Add new
```

**Example:**

```js
function fun() {
  var str = document.getElementById("h").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(str);
  var span = document.getElementById("s");
  span.innerHTML = ""; // Clear old content
  span.appendChild(t); // Add new
}
```

```html
some other text
<input type="hidden" value="&lt;strong&gt;boo&lt;/strong&gt;" id="h" />
<input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="click" />
<span id="s">change here</span>
```